# How Can I Attach Policy Tags to columns using Python API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client, google-data-catalog, data-governance

As a part of data governance, we have created Taxonomies, Policy Tags Using "Python API". And I am trying to Assign Policy Tags to Columns [Name, Age] for a table `Project.Dataset.TMP_TBL`.
Looked across the GCP Documentation but couldn't find any code snippets of Python to do this.
Please Help me out with and Example code Snippet to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [update_table()](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.update_table) to assign policy tags to columns. When updating a policy tag for a specific column see code below:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery.schema import SchemaField,PolicyTagList
client = bigquery.Client()

table_id = 'project_id.dataset_id.table_id'

policy_tags = PolicyTagList(names=["projects/<my_project_id>/locations/us/taxonomies/<taxonomy_id>/policyTags/<policy_tag_id>"])
table = client.get_table(table_id)

table.schema = [
        SchemaField(
            name="name",
            field_type="STRING",
            policy_tags=policy_tags
            ),
        SchemaField(
            name="age",
            field_type="INT64"
            )
        ]

table = client.update_table(table=table,fields=["schema"])
print(table.schema)
```

Output:

[image]

NOTE: For example you have a table with 2 columns (`name`, `age`). If you want to update the `policy_tag` for `name` only you can do so as shown with the code above. But you also need to redefine `age` so it won't error out.